# Can I use variables in XML for Android?

Tags: android, xml

Instead of using this following line for each textview:

```
android:textSize="40sp"
```

Am I able to replace 40sp with a variable?

As a side question, I've been recommended to use SP units as it goes by user defined settings. Is this a best practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I able to replace 40sp with a variable?

You can either use [a dimension resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) (e.g., `android:textSize="@dimen/someSize"`), or use a style that does this (per AlexN's answer), or set the size at runtime via `setTextSize()`.

> I've been recommended to use SP units as it goes by user defined settings. Is this a best practice?

On newer versions of Android, the user can change the base font size via the Settings application. By using `sp` for units, your font sizes will scale along with the base font size. If you use other units (e.g., `dp`), your font size will remain the same regardless of what the user has in Settings. It is impossible to say whether any given use of `sp` is a "best practice" or not -- I am sure that there are cases where allowing the font size to change would be a bad thing. By default, though, `sp` is probably the right starting point.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to use code based variables in XML files. However, you can use styles for this.

Example:

```
<style name="MyTvStyle">
  <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
</style>
```

Then apply it like this:

```
<TextView style="@style/MyTvStyle" ... />
```

A code based approach is also possible. If the TextViews have their `android:id` attribute defined you can retrieve them in the code with the `findViewById` method.

Example:

```
int[] id_array = {
    R.id.textview1, R.id.textview2, R.id.textview3 //Put all the id's of your textviews here
}

for(int i : id_array) { //Loop trough all the id's and retrieve the Textview associated with it.
    TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(i);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,40); //Set the text size to 40sp
}
```

And yes it's always better to use `sp` instead of normal pixel values. Since `sp` will scale with device size and user settings.

Answer (score 3):

As I know, using SP is a really good practice for Text Size.
And according to your first question - I think we cannot use variable, however, there is a better way. Check it out - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

So if you'll define a style, you can declare your Views in XML like `<TextView android:id = "@+id/myId" style = "@style/myStyle"/>`
And this style will incapsulate all parameters you want to set to your textViews on that screen.

Comment: Thank you. I did not even know about styles.